# Show multiple google maps in one page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

im using `hpneo gmaps` plugin: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

and i want to use multiple maps with different locations, now i have this code, but it shows only the first map

```
/* Google map */
var map1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      prettyPrint();
      map1 = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        scrollwheel: false,
        lat: 54.7181780,
        lng: 25.2204530,
        zoom: 16
      });

map1.addMarker({
        lat: 54.7181780,
        lng: 25.2204530,
        title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
        icon: '/images/marker.png'

      });
});

/* Vilnius */
var map2;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      prettyPrint();
      map2 = new GMaps({
        div: '#vilnius',
        scrollwheel: false,
        lat: 54.8900070,
        lng: 23.9255120,
        zoom: 10
      });

map2.addMarker({
        lat: 54.8900070,
        lng: 23.9255120,
        title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
        icon: '/images/marker.png'

      });
});
```

Here is fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/337T7/ - works fine, but if i want to display only the "vilnius" map and remove the `<div id="map" class="map"></div>` no one maps are displayed.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example at jsfiddle or the like?

Comment: Here: in this all work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/337T7/ but if i want to show only the map "vilnius" its not displaying (delete the <div id="map" class="map"></div> and run again)

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking whether the div exists before you try to call a function on it. The most simple way to do so is by placing the code within

```
if(document.getElementById('map)){
    //your code
}
```

Also, I think it would be good practice to put both chunks of code into one single document.ready

So the resulting code would be something like this:

```
var map1, map2;
$(document).ready(function(){
  prettyPrint();
  if(document.getElementById('map')){
    map1 = new GMaps({
      div: '#map',
      scrollwheel: false,
      lat: 54.7181780,
      lng: 25.2204530,
      zoom: 16
    });
    map1.addMarker({
      lat: 54.7181780,
      lng: 25.2204530,
      title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
      icon: '/images/marker.png'
    });
  }

  if(document.getElementById('vilnius')){
    prettyPrint();
    map2 = new GMaps({
      div: '#vilnius',
      scrollwheel: false,
      lat: 54.8900070,
      lng: 23.9255120,
      zoom: 10
    });
    map2.addMarker({
      lat: 54.8900070,
      lng: 23.9255120,
      title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
      icon: '/images/marker.png'
    });
  }
});
```

I believe it would be more elegant to not have the code related to one of the maps executed if the div isn't actually in the HTML by another way than by testing if the div if there. But I don't know how the structure of your project is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the div isn't there, the first call is throwing an error, which is canceling the remaining call. You'll want to check if the div is present: http://jsfiddle.net/337T7/1/

```
/* Google map */
var map1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#map').length) {
        prettyPrint();
        map1 = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            scrollwheel: false,
            lat: 54.7181780,
            lng: 25.2204530,
            zoom: 16
        });

        map1.addMarker({
            lat: 54.7181780,
            lng: 25.2204530,
            title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
            icon: 'http://silk.webmode.lt/wp-content/themes/silk_theme/images/marker.png'

        });
    }
});

/* Vilnius */
var map2;
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($('#vilnius').length) {
      prettyPrint();
      map2 = new GMaps({
        div: '#vilnius',
        scrollwheel: false,
        lat: 54.8900070,
        lng: 23.9255120,
        zoom: 10
      });

    map2.addMarker({
        lat: 54.8900070,
        lng: 23.9255120,
        title: 'II "Meistrus" ',
        icon: 'http://silk.webmode.lt/wp-content/themes/silk_theme/images/marker.png'

      });
   }
});
```

Comment: More specifically, gmaps is throwing a 'No element defined' error.

Comment: You should look at Chrome with it's Developer Tools, or Firefox and the like. The console can help you find such errors, and tell you where they are happening. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/